# Is there a way to disable the sleep/suspend chime?

Tags: settings, sound, suspend

I returned to elementary 6.1 after a year off with other distros. There's one new feature that's been really off-putting to me: I find the chime that plays when my laptop goes to suspend/sleep mode obnoxiously loud compared to all other sounds on the system, it's even woken me up right after going to sleep once and I'm not a light sleeper. I tried looking around for a way to configure the volume or disable it all together in the settings but I couldn't find anything referencing it.

Is there a way to completely disable this suspend chime?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an easy to overlook option found in `System Settings -> Sounds`

You just need to untick `Event alerts - Play sounds`